# Syntax doubling with .babelrc while trying to use babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Tags: ios, reactjs, syntax, babeljs

All,

I am trying to include babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties in my code bundle, but I get the following error;

**2020-01-07 08:19:31.593 [error][tid:NSOperationQueue 0x2817acc40 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)][RCTCxxBridge.mm:414] Failed to load bundle(http://169.254.99.36:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-plugin-proposal-class-properties' from '/Users/bburch/Projects/systems/SystemsDockConfig'
- Did you mean "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"? (null))**

My .babelrc looks like;

```
{   "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react",   ],   "plugins": ["proposal-class-properties",] }
```

I also have tried this syntax;

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

In either case, somehow the "plugin" part of the package name is being doubled and of course the module is not found when that happens.

My package.json;

```
{
  "name": "SystemsDockConfig",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
    "buffer": "^5.0.7",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eventemitter3": "^4.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-ble-plx": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-wheel-datepicker": "^2.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your .babelrc to babel.config.json and use{
make sure you install

```sh
npm i --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

this should work
**bable.config.json**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
        "plugins": [

            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
}
```